# Consulta a múltiplas tabelas no mysql

Tags: mysql, query

O meu modelo é o seguinte, tenho 4 tabelas

```
Avião (tailnum (PK), year)
Voos (id_voo (PK), cancelled)
Modelo (idmodel (PK), nome)
Fabricante (id_fabricante (PK), nome)
```

Avião está com uma ligação de 1:M com a tabela voos e modelo, e a tabela modelo está com uma ligação de 1:M com fabricante. 
Eu pretendo efetuar uma consulta do genero "Quais os aviões Boeing construidos antes do ano 2000 que tiveram voos cancelados".
Boeing é o nome do fabricante, e em relação aos voos cancelados na tabela voo está um booleano e que quando o valor = 1 o voo foi cancelado. Depois o ano está na tabela avião.

Eu estou a fazer deste modo:

```
Select tailnum
From
      (Select t.tailnum
       From Aviao t
       Inner Join Modelo M
       ON t.tailnum = M.tailnum
       Inner Join Fabricante C
       ON M.idmodel = C.idmodel
       Where nome = "Boeing"
       group by t.tailnum )
Where year < 2000 and tailnum IN (Select tailnum
                                  From voos
                                  where cancelled = 1)
```

Nesta eu vou buscar os aviões Boeing inferiores a 2000, como eu faço para agora ir à tabela voos e trazer os cancelled = 1.
Ainda me causa alguma confusão estas a idas a várias tabelas, será que alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Editei a parte de ir buscar à tabela voos segundo uns tutoriais que vi, estará correto assim?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui realizando a query da seguinte forma:

```
select distinct
   a.tailnum
from
   aviao a,
   voos v,
   fabricante f,
   modelo m
 where
   a.year < 2000 and
   f.nome = 'Boeing' and
   v.cancelled = 1 and
   a.tailnum = m.tailnum and
   f.id_fabricante = m.id_fabricante and
   a.tailnum = v.tailnum
```

Veja se lhe é útil.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcc79/3)

@EDIT

#### Utilizando Joins, que é a forma mais recomendada:

```
select 
   a.tailnum
from
   aviao a
   left join voos v 
   on a.tailnum = v.tailnum
   inner join modelo m 
   on m.tailnum = v.tailnum
   inner join fabricante f 
   on f.id_fabricante = m.id_fabricante   
 where
   a.year < 2000 and
   f.nome = 'Boeing' and
   v.cancelled = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec959/1)

Comment: Dá uma conferida se aplicação de joins ao invés de conectar pelo from é applicável, pois é mais otimizado internamente no banco de dados.

Comment: Isso é até uma boa questão (se ainda não fizeram). Particularmente não vejo diferença na questão da performance, mas vou pesquisar.

Comment: A questão é que usando joins da maneira correta não precisaria usar o distinct, aplicando join (mostra apenas registro correspondentes em ambas as tabelas) usando left outer join ou right outer join (retorna NULLS da tabela esquerda ou direita no join mesmo que sem correspondentes)

Comment: Perfeito. Vou revisar utilizando os joins.

Comment: Penso que já consegui através de joins, só preciso mesmo de testar com os dados reais, obrigado :)

Comment: Caso funcione posto aqui que pode ajudar alguém futuramente, caro fellipe se depois testou com joins poste aqui também para comparar.

Comment: @Gonçalo Feito!